# Firebase functions rewrite rule /** not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

We are using Firebase functions and taking advantage of the hosting/rewrite feature to direct URLs to run Firebase functions. We cannot get the rules to behave exactly as we want and are hoping for some guidance.

firebase.json

```
{
  ...
  "hosting": {
    ...
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/function_a",
        "function": "function_a"
      },
      {
        "source": "/function_a/subcategory",
        "function": "function_a_subcategory"
      },
      {
        "source": "/**",
        "function": "function_b"
      }
  ]
  }
}
```

Expected result:

```
1. /function_a --> function_a()
2. /function_a/subcategory --> function_a_subcategory()
3. /anything else --> function_b()
```

Actual result:

```
1. /function_a --> function_b()
2. /function_a/subcategory --> function_b()
3. /anything else --> function_b()
```

Essentially we want any glob patterns that are defined to go to their respective destination and anything else would go to `function_b`. What are we doing wrong here?

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate this behavior using just that set of rewrite rules, and assuming that the 3 functions actually are visibly different to the user.  I got the behavior you describe as expected.  Is there other context that might be needed to create a [mre]?

Comment: I revisited this and I was actually able to get it working by removing all the rewrites, deploying, and then adding them again and deploying again. I don't know if it was something on my end or Firebase but I suppose it's fixed for now! When I initially added the rewrites, it was not all at once so maybe that affects it somehow?